# Dynamic struct array terminating early

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic, struct, allocation

I'm refreshing my knowledge of C++ dynamic memory allocation and structs, and suddenly ran into some trouble. Below is the part of code, which stops executing after 3 line and the program terminates.

```
int n;
std::cout << "How many hotels do you want : ";
std::cin >> n;


hotel* hotels= new (nothrow) hotel[n];

for (int i= 0; i< n; i++) {
    std::cout << "Hotel " << i+1 << " name : ";
    std::cin >> hotels[i].name;
    std::cout << "Hotel " << i+1 << " rating : ";
    std::cin >> hotels[i].rating;
    std::cout << "Hotel " << i+1 << " stars : ";
    std::cin >> hotels[i].stars;
}
```

Here is the "hotel" declaration:

```
struct hotel {
    char* name;
    short int rating, stars;
};
```

I'm guessing there is something wrong with the dynamic declaration of "hotels".  Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: You did not allocate any space for `hotel::name`, unless you didn't show the constructor. Why don't you try a `string` instead?

Comment: I'd be using `std::string` and `std::vector` here, since this is actually C++.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `new (nothrow)` if you aren't going to check the return value for `NULL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, you need to allocated your `char*`. If not you will have an undefined behaviour (generally a `segFault`)

There is two more things in your code :

You should use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead of `char*`. It is a better practice in C++. (At least in this case) :

```
#include <string>

struct hotel {
    std::string name;
  //^^^^^^^^^^^
    short int rating, stars;
};
```

You may also want to use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you need to allocate memory for `char* name` in your struct in order to store characters.

You can also use `string` instead of `char *` if you are using C++ (preferred way):

```
struct hotel {
    string name;
    short int rating, stars;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to include `new` to be able to use `nothrow`
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/nothrow/

```
#include <new>  //std::nothrow
```